# SQL Server performance expectations

Tags: sql-server, database-performance

Our development team wants us to investigate whether current hardware is adequate for the needs.The application they use has always been slow and they want to make sure we have no hardware bottleneck
 We are using following configuration for the MS SQL 2005 Standard:

Server: HP DL 380 G5
OS: Windows Server 2003 R2 Standard x64 Edition Service Pack 2
SQL Server: MS SQL 2005 Standard Edition x64 bit
Memory: 6 GB
CPUs: 2 x Intel Xeon 5140  L1 64 KB, L2 4 MB
Storage
OS + tmpdb : 32 GB SAS drive in RAID 1
Data: 300 GB LUN on FC Clariion CX3-10 SAN, RAID 5, FC Disks
Log: 100 GB on same SAN RAID 5 disk group.

Other servers in our environment have a similiar configuration and there are no complaints about them.
There are few queries that are not optimized and many indexes are not done often enough, so I suspect that developers should work more on optimizing their queries.
Biggest problem here is that I don't know where to start.Surely I can ran perfom and present graphs showing Disk Queue , CPU time and other performance related data.
 Can I run some general test that would show problems with SQL configuration?
I understand that each workload is different but I need to start somewhere.
So far I started collecting data with perfmon to see if I can see any correlation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the information I was after:

http://www.grumpyolddba.co.uk/monitoring/Performance%20Counter%20Guidance%20-%20SQL%20Server.htm

http://www.grumpyolddba.co.uk/monitoring/Performance%20Counter%20Guidance%20-%20Windows%20Server.htm